# How to get the target number with +3 or *5 operations without recursion?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

This is an interview problem I came across yesterday, I can think of a recursive solution but I wanna know if there's a non-recursive solution.

Given a number N, starting with number 1, you can only multiply the result by 5 or add 3 to the result. If there's no way to get N through this method, return "Can't generate it".

Ex:

```
Input: 23
Output: (1+3)*5+3
Input: 215
Output: ((1*5+3)*5+3)*5
Input: 12
Output: Can't generate it.
```

The recursive method can be obvious and intuitive, but are there any non-recursive methods?

Answer (score 16):

I think the quickest, non recursive solution is (for N > 2):

- if `N mod 3 == 1`, it can be generated as `1 + 3*k`.
- if `N mod 3 == 2`, it can be generated as `1*5 + 3*k`
- if `N mod 3 == 0`, it cannot be generated

The last statement comes from the fact that starting with 1 (= 1 mod 3) you can only reach numbers which are equals to 1 or 2 mod 3:

- when you add 3, you don't change the value mod 3
- a number equals to 1 mod 3 multiplied by 5 gives a number equals to 2 mod 3
- a number equals to 2 mod 3 multiplied by 5 gives a number equals to 1 mod 3

Comment: This solves the decision problem quite brilliantly, but it does not solve the construction problem the way the OP has intended: `215` would be generated as `1*5+3+3+3...+3` with `+3` repeated 70 times, not as `((1*5+3)*5+3)*5`.

Comment: The method is cool, pure mathematical analysis. But as @dasblinkenlight says, the result format is not what I want. Is there any way to print it exactly like what it requires?

Comment: You're right, it doesn't produce the best solution (unless N can't be generated!). But getting the shortest solution is a much more difficult problem. And the recursive solution really seems the easiest way to go.

Comment: @obourgain In my opinion you solved the more subtle problem of efficiently deciding whether or not number can be reached. Finding the shortest solution  to `N` is an "off-the-shelf" application of Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: The shortest solution is not that difficult of a problem, and my solution is about O(N) (where N is number of digits, so O(log(N)) for size of number)

Answer (score 5):

The key here is to work backwards.  Start with the number you want to reach and if it's divisible by 5 then divide by 5 because multiplication by 5 results in a shorter solution than addition by 3.  The only exceptions are if the value equals 10, because dividing by 5 would yield 2 which is insolvable.  If the number is not divisible by 5 or is equal to 10, subtract 3.  This produces the shortest string

Repeat until you reach 1

Here is python code:

```
def f(x):
    if x%3 == 0 or x==2:
        return "Can't generate it"
    l = []
    while x!=1:
        if x%5 != 0 or x==10:
            l.append(3)
            x -= 3
        else:
                l.append(5)
                x /=5
    l.reverse()
    s = '1'
    for v in l:
        if v == 3:
            s += ' + 3'
        else:
            s = '(' + s + ')*5'
    return s
```

Credit to the previous solutions for determining whether a given number is possible

Comment: yes, it is a better idea to search backwards from the target number `N` rather than forwards from `1` as I suggested. The idea of preferring `/5` to `-3` is particularly astute, and I think could be justified mathematically, e.g. using proof by contradiction (it ought to be possible to show that if you have the choice of subtracting 3 from `N` or dividing by 5, subtracting 3 will take more steps).

Comment: It's a fairly simple proof, although it's not in strict mathematical language:  If there is the opportunity to divide by 5, and you instead subtract 3, you would have to subtract 5 times in order to get another chance to divide by 5.  If you then divide by 5 it takes a total of 6 steps.  If however, you divide by 5 first and then subtract 3, it takes 2 steps.  The only scenario in which you would not want to divide by 5, is at 10, because if you do you will be left with 2 which is impossible to generate.

Comment: Sounds too simple to me, and the fact that for 10 it's clearly wrong stands as more evidence.  I'll see if I can think of other counterexamples.

Comment: I have proven to myself that the reasoning is solid down to 15.

Answer (score 2):

Model the problem as a graph:

- Nodes are numbers
- Your root node is 1
- Links between nodes are `*5` or `+3`.

Then run [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to get the shortest path. If you exhaust all links from nodes `<N` without getting to `N` then you can't generate `N`. (Alternatively, use @obourgain's answer to decide in advance whether the problem can be solved, and only attempt to work out how to solve the problem if it *can* be solved.)

So essentially, you enqueue the node (1, null path). You need a dictionary storing {node(i.e. number) => best path found so far for that node}. Then, so long as the queue isn't empty, in each pass of the loop you

- Dequeue the head (node,path) from the queue.
- If the number of this node is `>N`, or you've already seen this node before with fewer steps in the path, then don't do any more on this pass.
- Add (node => path) to the dictionary.
- Enqueue nodes reachable from this node with `*5` and `+3` (together with the paths that get you to those nodes)

When the loop terminates, look up `N` in the dictionary to get the path, or output "Can't generate it".

*Edit*: note, this is really [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) rather than Dijkstra's algorithm, as the cost of traversing a link is fixed at 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following recursion (which is indeed intuitive):

```
f(input) = f(input/5) OR f(input -3)
base:
f(1) = true
f(x) = false    x is not natural positive number
```

Note that it can be done using Dynamic Programming as well:

```
f[-2] = f[-1] = f[0] = false
f[1] = true
for i from 2 to n:
   f[i] = f[i-3] or (i%5 == 0? f[i/5] : false)
```

To get the score, you need to get on the table after building it from `f[n]` and follow the valid `true` moves.

Time and space complexity of the DP solution is `O(n)` [pseudo-polynomial]

Answer (score 0):

All recursive algorithms can also be implemented using a stack.  So, something like this:

```
bool canProduce(int target){
Stack<int> numStack;
int current;

numStack.push(1);

while(!numStack.empty){
  current=numStack.top();
  numStack.pop();
  if(current==target)
    return true;
  if(current+3 < target)
    numStack.push(current+3);
  if(current*5 < target)
    numStack.push(current*5);
}

return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

The smart solution:

```
def f(n):
    if n % 3 == 1:
        print '1' + '+3' * (n // 3)
    elif n % 3 == 2:
        print '1*5' + '+3' * ((n - 5) // 3)
    else:
        print "Can't generate it."
```

A naive but still O(n) version:

```
def f(n):
    d={1:'1'}
    for i in range(n):
        if i in d:
            d[i*5] = '(' + d[i] + ')*5'
            d[i+3] = d[i] + '+3'

    if n in d:
        print d[n]
    else:
        print "Can't generate it."
```

And of course, you could also use a stack to reproduce the behavior of the recursive calls.

Which gives:

```
>>> f(23)
(1)*5+3+3+3+3+3+3
>>> f(215)
(1)*5+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3
>>> f(12)
Can't generate it.
```