# Finding a sequence of operations

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

This should eventually be written in JavaScript. But I feel that I should not type any code until my algorithm is clear, which it is not!

Problem Given: Starting at 1, write a function that given a number returns a sequence of operations that consist only of either `"+5"` or `"*3"` that produce the number in question.

My basic algorithm:

1. Get the number
2. if the number is 1
     return 1.
3. else if we surpass the number
     return -1.
4. else keep trying to `"+5"` or `"*3"` until number is reached, assuming it can be reached.

My problem is with step # 4: I see that there are two paths to take which will bring me to the number in question(target), either `"+5"` OR `"*3"`, but what about the number 13 which can be found by a MIXTURE of BOTH paths?? I can only do one thing or the other!
How would I know which path to take and how many times I should take that path? How would I bounce back and forth between paths?

Comment: Have you checked this out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652190/how-to-get-the-target-number-with-3-or-5-operations-without-recursion

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the concept of breadth first search in a binary tree. However, I suggest turning the problem around, and looking at the problem of using "-5" or "/3" to get from the target back to 1. That allows pruning based on the target.

For example, 13 is not divisible by 3, so the first step in the backwards problem for target 13 must be "-5", not "/3".

It does not change the complexity, but may make the algorithm faster in practice for small problems.

Answer (score 0):

You essentially want to do a breadth first, binary search tree.  You could use recursion, or just some while loops.  Each step you take the current number and add 5 or multiply by 3.  Do your tests, and if you find the input value, then return 0 or something (You did not specify).

The key here is to thing about the data structure and how to search it.  Do you understand why it should be breadth first?  Do you understand why it is a binary tree?

In response to comments:
First off I admire your efforts.  Solving this kind of problem, independent of language, is a great way to approach a problem.  It is not about stupid trick in Javascript (or any other language).

So the first concept to get down is that you "searching" for a solution, if you don't find one return -1.

Second you should do some research on binary trees.  They are a very important concept!

Third you should then go breadth first search.  However, that is the least important.  It just makes the problem a bit more efficient.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am no computer science major and therefor not familiar with those topics. I am self learning. I got the problem from chapter 3 in a book called eloquent JavaScript. What do you recommend I should research to understand this?

Comment: I meant the breadth and binary tree is what im not familiar with by the way.

Comment: @DEdesigns57 I suggest searching for "binary tree", "breadth first", "depth first", and "recursion". Alternatively, look for a book on algorithms that has those terms in its index, and read it.

Answer (score 0):

`what about the number 13 which can be found by a MIXTURE of BOTH paths?? I can only do one thing or the other!`

Well, actually you can do both. As in the example in [chapter 3](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html) of the book you mention, you'll see that the function `find` is called twice inside itself -- the function is trying both paths at any choice point and the first correct solution is returned (you could also experiment with altering the overall function so it will return all correct paths).

`How would I know which path to take and how many times I should take that path? How would I bounce back and forth between paths?`

Basically, bouncing back and forth between paths is achieved by traveling both of them. You know if it's the right path if the function hits the target number.